# viewpager inside linearlayout does not respect weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

i have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#A00A0A"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="New Switch" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my problem is  that the ViewPager fills the parent's height no matter the settings, or weights i put in and the Switch is not seen

how do i fix this?

Comment: set the weight to 1 for the view pager

Answer (score 2):

If you are using weight for height, then your height should be 0dp. Try this answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#A00A0A"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="New Switch" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this does correct this, i noticed that as "AndroidEnthusiast" said, chaging the weight to "1" solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you set `ViewPager`'s height `wrap_content` it'll not matter. It acts like

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You have to set a certain `dimension` like

```
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

Or if you use it inside a `RelativeLayout` you can use

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

or you have to set your switch `alignParentBottom` and set your `ViewPager` above of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/my_switch">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#A00A0A"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" 
        />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/my_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="New Switch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: We cannot use layout_alighParentBottom to switch inside a LinearLayout. layout_alighParentBottom is a property of RelativeLayout. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right. I did not realize it. Because you used android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true in your root view. You have to change it to relative layout.